# it takes 2 seconds to compile a hello world C++ project in netbeans (windows)

Tags: c++, netbeans

I used code:blocks as the C++ IDE on Windows. I switched to netbeans 6.8 (with C/C++ plugin, MinGW, MSYS) recently, because netbeas have the nice feature of "checking syntax errors when typing" (same as working on Java or PHP projects).

But the painful thing is that, it takes 2 seconds to compile a simple hello world project in netbeans. Any trick to make it as fast as code:blocks, or at least make the compiling time no more than 0.5 second?

EDIT:
I did not care about this 2 seconds difference until I worked on Google codejam questions yesterday.

Comment: This question makes me want to shake my old-man cane and yell "Get off my lawn, you darn kids!"

Comment: Why it is that slow? Is it really absurd to use a Java-based IDE for C++ projects?

Comment: You are complaining about 2 seconds when it can take hours or perhaps even days to compile a C++ program!! - I have also seen a program on a forum that literally puts the compiler in an infinite loop...

Comment: Ya... Lots of my apps take **minutes** to compile.

Comment: Besides - have you done any research to see if it is really the compiler that is taking 1.5 extra seconds or your IDE?

Comment: @George: I think it is the compiler time. The output window of netbeans shows "BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2s)"

Comment: I just skimmed Google Code Jam's website; I was not previously familiar with the competition.  That said, I question whether a difference of 1.5 seconds per compilation (since you say that a time of 0.5 seconds is acceptable) will matter to your overall performance.  _Especially_ when you subtract the time it took you to post and monitor this SO question.

Comment: @Lord: the qualification round give the competitors a whole day to work on it. The problems is the next rounds.

Comment: @Ethan: Just because it says `(total time: 2s)` doesn't mean the compiler took 2 sec. to build it. It probably means that 2 seconds have elapsed since the compilation was started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MinGW uses G++ 3.x, which is very very old. It's a limitation of the compiler itself -- old versions of G++ are simply slow. There are some "unofficial" G++ ports to windows that borrow from the MinGW project that use more recent (4.x) versions of G++, and it's possible your Code::Blocks IDE was using one of those.

I seriously doubt that the second and a half is significant in 99.9% of usages of most compilers anyway. Even if it is overhead imposed by the IDE itself, we're talking about what is essentially a one time cost -- it shouldn't blow up to insane compile times when you compile larger programs.

---

In response to FredOverflow's comment: From the MinGW installer (mingw.ini):

```
[mingw]
Build=12
URL=http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw
Filename=MinGW-5.1.6.exe
packages=previous|current|candidate

[current]
runtime=mingwrt-3.17-mingw32-dev.tar.gz|7300
runtimeDLL=mingwrt-3.17-mingw32-dll.tar.gz|30
w32api=w32api-3.14-mingw32-dev.tar.gz|14460
binutils=binutils-2.20-1-mingw32-bin.tar.gz|26979
core=gcc-core-3.4.5-20060117-3.tar.gz|7712
gpp=gcc-g++-3.4.5-20060117-3.tar.gz|15480
g77=gcc-g77-3.4.5-20060117-3.tar.gz|5272
ada=gcc-ada-3.4.5-20060117-3.tar.gz|33860
java=gcc-java-3.4.5-20060117-3.tar.gz|43160
objc=gcc-objc-3.4.5-20060117-3.tar.gz|3720
make=make-3.81-20090914-mingw32-bin.tar.gz|723

[previous]
runtime=mingwrt-3.15.2-mingw32-dev.tar.gz|7616
runtimeDLL=mingwrt-3.15.2-mingw32-dll.tar.gz|40
w32api=w32api-3.13-mingw32-dev.tar.gz|14420
binutils=binutils-2.19.1-mingw32-bin.tar.gz|21093
core=gcc-core-3.4.2-20040916-1.tar.gz|8627
gpp=gcc-g++-3.4.2-20040916-1.tar.gz|16542
g77=gcc-g77-3.4.2-20040916-1.tar.gz|5158
ada=gcc-ada-3.4.2-20040916-1.tar.gz|33333
java=gcc-java-3.4.2-20040916-1.tar.gz|45547
objc=gcc-objc-3.4.2-20040916-1.tar.gz|4555
make=mingw32-make-3.81-20080326-2.tar.gz|727

[candidate]
binutils=binutils-2.18.50-20080109-2.tar.gz|20505
core=gcc-core-3.4.5-20060117-3.tar.gz|7712
gpp=gcc-g++-3.4.5-20060117-3.tar.gz|15480
g77=gcc-g77-3.4.5-20060117-3.tar.gz|5272
ada=gcc-ada-3.4.5-20060117-3.tar.gz|33860
java=gcc-java-3.4.5-20060117-3.tar.gz|43160
objc=gcc-objc-3.4.5-20060117-3.tar.gz|3720
make=mingw32-make-3.81-2.tar.gz|720
```

Comment: No, I use the same version MinGW for netbeans and Code:Blocks. Actually I set the path of compliers in netbeans pointing to those use with MinGW. I know it is probably a one-time cost, but it is still uncomfortable when I need to repetitively compile small projects many many times to check if they work correctly. I am working on Google codejam questions.

Comment: What do you mean, "unofficial"? You can get the latest g++ 4.5.0 as part of the official [MinGW package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/).

Comment: @FredOverflow: The item you linked to contains G++ 3.4.4

Comment: @Billy THe GCC 4.5 compiler is actually on the MinGW SourceForge site, but that site is so abysmally unusable I can't blame anyone for not finding it. I cannot see why ANYONE continues to use SourceForge, but MinGW have added their own levels of impenetrability to it.

Comment: @Billy That's the installer - there isn't one for 4.5, or any recent versions, but that doesn't mean those versions don't exist. That's why everyone uses the "unoficial" releases by people like Twilight Dragon and nuwen.

Comment: @Billy I downloaded 4.5 just fine from that site under "GCC version 4". `g++ --version` confirms that this is really 4.5.0. You simply have to download and extract the files listed unter "runtime requirements" in [the readme](http://sunet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/mingw/GCC%20Version%204/gcc-4.5.0-1/gcc-4.5.0-1-mingw32.RELEASE_NOTES.txt).

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: That is correct and is why I said "unofficial" above. @FredOverflow: I was not aware of that. However the fact that no installer exists for 4.5 is still a major problem. No IDE bundles the 4.5 version because the latest installer has only the 3.4.4 version. When the installer is fixed I might start recommending GCC again for Windows, but until then I cannot. (It's an *EXCELLENT* compiler on *nix platforms though)

Comment: @Billy The TD release is at 4.4.1, comes as an installer, and works perfectly.

Comment: Just upgrade MinGW to TDM's GCC/MinGW32 Builds (http://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/). Compiling time reduces to 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

Two seconds to load a compiler, compile a source file, assemble it, and link it is actually pretty fast. The speed difference may be due to the very large memory footprint of Netbeans compared with the quite small one for Code:;Blocks. Netbeans is more or less unusable on my ancient laptop, whereas Code::Blocks works just fine.

Comment: Two seconds is pretty fast? Turbo Pascal could do this instantly 25 years ago, and its only advantage was having the compiler already in memory.

Comment: for a hello world app, 2 seconds is a long time. For larger projects, of course, 2 seconds is nothing.

Comment: @Gabe: The C++ standard library didn't exist 25 years ago, so how do you know? (Compilation of HelloWorld with "cstdio" should be instantaneous, whereas "iostream" is a beast only surpassed by some boost libraries :) )

Comment: @Gabe: Pascal != C++. They have completely different linking models. Comparing one to the other is inherently not a meaningful comparison.

Comment: Computers are 1000 times faster and have 1000 times the memory of computers from 25 years ago that could compile and link a program in 20ms. I know C++ is more complicated than Pascal, but not 100,000 times more complicated!

Comment: @Gabe: Hard disks are not 1000 times faster, and when compiling a hello world program the disk is going to be the bottleneck, not anything like CPU or RAM. Your assertion that a 1000 times faster CPU with 1000 times the memory is 100,000 times as fast is false. Finally, when compiling that hello world program, the compiler could be processing several MB of source code as a result of `#include` ing various standard library headers.

Comment: One might hope that somewhere withing those thousands of megabytes of memory, there might be room to cache things like the compiler, linker, object files, and so on. That way the first compiler would be slow because everything has to be loaded from disk, but successive ones would be much faster.

Comment: @billy I have to agree with @gabe here. I think you guys have just gotten so use to poor compilation time you've come to accept it's mediocre performance. You say, pascal and c++ has different models of building? ok that's fair enough, let's compare apples to apples then. Consider the Borland/Codegear C++ compiler in C++ Builder 2007. From my test, I found that compiler finish builds order of magnitude faster than gcc.

Comment: And this is a real world project framework: wxWidgets; not some contrived hello world toy program. Check my post here for details if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470864/mingw-gcc-pch-not-speeding-up-wxwidget-build-times-is-my-setup-correct

Comment: @Victor T: 1. You're really bringing up something from May 10th? 2. Codegear's C++ compiler is non-compliant. Things like correct handling of templates and exceptions and namespaces take CPU time. 3. A basic wxWidgets application builds and links in less than ten seconds on my machine... no idea where you're getting the 8+ minute figures -- even those few projects I work on that use boost::spirit build and link faster than that.

Comment: @Billy i'm not talking about building a project that uses wxwidgets. I'm talking about actually building the wxwidgets library itself. As far as compliance goes, the compiler seems to work well enough. The only thing that toolchain has trouble with is really advance template usage. My point still stands though -- while all those things you've mention certainly takes time to process, it should not take the amount that we're seeing today, especially with faster processors.

Comment: @Victor T.: Yes, the only thing it has trouble with is only **the most CPU intensive and complicated part of the language**. Well, I'm not surprised. If you don't care about supporting the language correctly, you too can have really fast compile times. If you think that there's some conspiracy in the GCC team to make their compiler slow for some reason, show me the piece of source causing the slowness -- it's open after all. Also, GCC spends a lot more time doing optimization than Borland/Codegear, and produces faster binaries for the same code. That doesn't come for free.